# "The relationship could not be changed bc one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable" - But not deleting anything

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to SaveChanges() on my context after adding a number of Order entities:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

Now I know what the error means, and I've googled around a great deal. The thing is, I'm not removing anything or overwriting anything (that I know of).

I got this error in my main application while importing orders from Amazon, so I stripped out the code into a console application to try to narrow it down, but so far no luck.

The console application is now doing the bare minimum I can think of to recreate the error - simply creating two test orders and calling Save. Now the interesting thing here is ***two*** test orders - not one. If I just add one order and call Save I don't get the error - it only happens when I have more than one added to the entity list.

(Now I could just call Save() after every Add but with lots of orders to import, it's a fair bit slower. Besides, I'd like to get to the bottom of this - it was working once)

I was thinking of recent changes I have made to the application that might have caused this - there is one but I am struggling to think of ways it could have caused this.

Previously, every Order record had a (nullable) relationship to a table called Payments. I removed that table (and the relationships) from the model and created a similar table & relationship called Receipts. (The idea being that every Order will have Zero or One Receipt entities associated with it).

The test orders are being added without Receipts (which is valid, according to the model - ReceiptId is nullable) and I can't find any trace of the old Payments table anywhere.

If there a way to find out which relationship this error is complaining about so that I might be able to narrow this down some more?

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

        var orders = GetOrders(unitOfWork);

        foreach (var order in orders)
        {
            unitOfWork.OrdersRepository.AddOrder(order);
        }

        unitOfWork.Save();

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Order> GetOrders(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        // Use defaults
        var country = unitOfWork.CountriesRepository.GetCountryById(223);
        var source = unitOfWork.OrderSourceRepository.GetSourceById("AMZ");
        var impression = unitOfWork.PostageImpressionRepository.GetPostageImpressionById(1);

        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            yield return
                new Order
                    {
                        Address1 = "Address 1",
                        Address2 = "Address 2",
                        Address3 = "Address 3",
                        Town = "Town ",
                        County = "County",
                        EMail = "test@test.com",
                        ExternalOrderRef = "Ref",
                        FullName = "Test Order " + i,
                        OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
                        OrderSource = source,
                        Postcode = "AA11AA",
                        Telephone = "0123456789",
                        ExternalStatus = "New",
                        Total = 1.23m,
                        Paid = true,
                        PaidDate = DateTime.Now,
                        ShippedDate = null,
                        Cancelled = false,
                        Country = country,
                        Receipt = null,
                        PostageImpression = impression,
                        SubTotal = 1.23m,
                        PostageCost = 0.00m
                    };
        }
    }
```

Comment: A sketch of your test console application's *code* would probably help to narrow the problem down.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be the fact that I had overridden Equals() on the entity object, which has confused Entity Framework.

See here for more info:

http://axilis.hr/entity-framework-override-equals-problem

I solved this by upgrading to EF 6.